# Can't install Netbeans/JDK 7 on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: apt, java, openjdk, jdk, netbeans

I am having trouble trying to install Netbeans/JDK 7 on Ubuntu.

When i try to install Netbeans, it asks for JDK 7, but i was unable to install it via apt-get.

I've tried this command already:
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

But i get the following error:
E: Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1):

Error **E: Package 'package_name' has no installation candidate** most probably means that the APT cannot find (i.e. download) the installation package.

To solve this, open **Software and Updates** and try changing *Download from* server (choose *Main* first). On my system it's Server for United States.

If it still does not work, then you can manually download the .deb package and install it.

[image: Software and Updates]